# Store data as a reference field in firestore using the addDoc function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently building an expense-tracker app and I want the transactions collection to have a category field. The category field should be of type "reference" and it should refer to another collection "categories". I tried this, but when I use the addDoc function the field category is stored as a map. And to be honest: It makes sense based on my code, but I don't know how to fix it.

Does anyone know how i can change that code, so the category is stored as a reference field in the firestore database?

```
const transaction = { category: {}, description: "", date: "", price: 0, userId: null} as Transaction
```

```
await addDoc(collection(db, "transactions"), {
    ...inputValues,
    category: {
        ...selectedOption
    },
    userId: user?.uid,
})
```

Comment: How are `selectedOption` (and `inputValues`  and `user` if those are relevant) initialized?

Comment: If I understood you correctly then like this:
`const transaction = { category: {}, description: "", date: "", price: 0, userId: null} as Transaction ` @FrankvanPuffelen